# how do I join spatially polygons to polygons, creating new rows as required?

Tags: qgis, polygon, spatial-join

I have two polygons layers - counties and urban-mega-messes (UMM). I have a shapefile for each. I would like to spatially join the county attribute information to the UMM layer and create a new joined file, answering: what counties are the UMM's located in?

In many cases, the UMM's are in multiple counties, in which case I would like additional rows to be added to the joined shapefile for each county in which they are contained.

UMM 1     COUNTY 1
UMM 1     COUNTY 2
etc

For example, the UMM "New York City" is in multiple counties.

I have been trying Data Management Tools -> Join attributes by location, but only 1 county record is appended to each UMM in the joined table - no additional rows are added.

I've searched online but found no answer. Is there a plugin that would do the trick? Or another tool in QGIS?

Comment: I realize a spatial join isn't exactly what I want, because the UMM polys in the resulting "joined" file will have different geo than in the original. So... join and split? Is that a thing?

Comment: You need a relate, which covers "one to many" relationships.

Comment: Try "INTERSECTION" tool and use as input layer your UMM and as intersect layer the COUNTY layer. That will create a new layer where each UMM feature will split depending on the COUNTY that it falls in.

Answer (score 1):

The INTERSECTION tool worked perfectly in this case.